# How to enable/disable load time weaving based on a config property

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, java-annotations, load-time-weaving

I've successfully enabled AspectJ's LoadTimeWeaving in my Spring project by annotating the configuration class with `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` and adding an `aop.xml`.

However, I want to make it config-driven such that by default it is off and is only enabled when some configuration property is set. To that end, I see `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` takes an attribute `aspectjWeaving` which can be either `ENABLED`, `DISABLED`, or `AUTODETECT` (also the default).

Can we somehow set the value of the `aspectjWeaving` attribute by reading some config from a properties file? Or, is there any other way to make it conditionally enable/disable?

It's not a Spring Boot application.

Comment: An annotation value is static so no you cannot do that. When using Spring Boot it would be quite easy to do conditional inclusion of that configuration.

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered, even though two people wrote an answer. Please inspect the answers, then either accept and upvote one or comment on it if you do not understand it. Thank you.

Comment: It seems the answer is "it is not possible", so correct that neither answer is ticked. Sepcifically "by reading some config from a properties file" has not been answered at all.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This answer is independent of Spring. It is just about ApsectJ. But it is possible to do this in a Spring or SpringBoot project as well.

If it is weaving itself that you want to control and not what happens inside the advice, then there are the following possible ways:

### 1. Don't pass the Java agent parameter

Though this may sound trivial as an answer, it is **safe and powerful**. This will turn off all load time weaving, which is what we want sometimes.

(Just for reference, when we want to weave, we pass `-javaagent:<path-to-aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar>` as JVM parameter.)

### 2. Add excludes in `aop.xml`

If it is specific sets of classes that you want to exclude from weaving, then exclude them in the `<weaver>` tag. You may refer to the exact syntax here: [Eclipse AspectJ docs](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html).

```xml
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <exclude within="test..*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        ...
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

### 3. Control at the level of pointcuts

You may also add `if()` to your pointcuts and skip the weaving using some condition, say a Java system property. Here is an example that skips all test code if there is a system property `skip.tests` set to `y` or `Y`.

```java
@Pointcut( "execution( * test..*(..) ) && if()" )
public static boolean allTestCode(){
    String instr = System.getProperty( "skip.tests", "n" );
    return instr.equalsIgnoreCase( "Y" );
}
```

### 4. Control inside the advice

*(This is not what you are asking for, but I am adding here just for completion; it may help someone else who has similar needs.)*

In this method, allow all weaving to happen, but execute advised code only conditionally (say, based on a configuration).

```java
@Around( "allTestCode()" )
public Object aroundAllTestCode( ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint ){
    /* Config controlled execution */
    if( System.getProperty( "advice.enabled" ).equalsIgnoreCase( "Y" ) ) applyAdvice();
    
    return thisJoinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry, saw this only today. I guess you wanted to address the questioner  (@saharsh-jain) and not me. You may want to repost this against the question.

Comment: One remark that may be confusing in this post:
if using the aspectWeaver java agent it's fully independent of Spring and needs to be used without the @EnableLoadTimeWeaving annotation.

Answer (score -1):

Use classical XML configuration instead of annotations, then it is "config-driven", if what you mean by this term is a file which you do not need to compile.

According to the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#context-load-time-weaver), simply use

```xml
<beans>
    <context:load-time-weaver/>
</beans>
```

Comment: I don't think "config-driven" means a file that's not compiled - rather that it can be changed at runtime. In my example I want to use JAR weaving in production but runtime weaving when running locally.